# Specifying Resource Field For Labeling in ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, labeling

How do I specify which field acts as resource for labeling a layer using ArcPy?

Following code is some settings that I am doing on a standalone ArcPy snippet and as you can see I added `layer.showLabels = True` but assuming I have a field named `name` I do not know how to add it to the code.

```
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("Primary")
layer.minScale = 10000
layer.showLabels = True
```

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299795/specifying-resource-field-for-labeling-in-arcpy#comment482511_299795):

> You need to specify a labelClass object
>   https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/LabelClass/00s30000002t000000/
>   - even if you have only one class, look at the example in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the label class object set the expression using the `expression` property:

> **expression:**
>   Provides the ability to get or set a layer's individual label class
>   expression. This can be as simple as a single field or more advanced
>   using either a VBScript, JScript or Python expression.

```
for lblClass in lyr.labelClasses:
    if lblClass.showClassLabels:
        lblClass.expression = lblClass.expression = "\"<FNT name='Arial' size='12'>\"  &  [MyFieldNameHere] & \"</FNT>\""
```